Footnotes in scribus
I'm new to Scribus. I'm trying to create a footnote using Insert/Marks, but that option appears disabled in the Insert menu. I have read that I should activate content editing mode but I don't know how to do it. Any help is welcome.

If you got to the point where you want to insert a footnote, you have for sure already used the edit mode: it's the mode you activate when typing the text in a frame (it's normally activated by double clicking on a frame; as an alternative you can type the E key while the frame is selected).
The reason why you can't (yet) insert a footnote, it's to be searched elsewhere: notes are an experimental feature.
If you really want to use them, you need to go to the preferences, in the experimental section, and turn on the usage of the notes.
An important warning: before massively using the footnotes, do a test run of the planned use cases and make sure that everything works as you expect.
It's not without reasons that they are deactivated by default: As of Scribus 1.6.2, there are still a few bugs in there!

You have to open a Story Editor by right-clicking on text frame and selecting "Edit Text", than place your cursor where you want the footnote to be, and go to Insert > Marks > Footnote. And to format a footnote go back to the main Scribus interface and use the Properties window (F2). Let me know if it works!
